# Autofilter - how to create array out of variables

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have column A with some names, each string which resambles name is in one cell (note 2 spaces before brackets):

```
Doe, John  (New York)
Smith, Will  (Philadelphia)
Banks, Carlton  (LA)
```

Then on the other sheet I have column A with a list of multiple names with the same format.
I'd like to create an array to use it in the autofilter in Excel.

Given that I know how to create a loop to go through all names, could you please help me creating the array in a suitable format?

I tried the below but it doesn't work, filter hides all names.
When I Debug.Print variable kryterium I get exactly the string I need:

```
If k > 0 Then
   kryterium = kryterium & ", " & sNameStat
Else
   kryterium = sNameStat
End If

ary = Split(kryterium, ", ")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$49").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use VBA?
I would add a couple of extra columns with the names extracted and apply a data filter to those columns.

Surname column: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`

Forename column: `=MID(A1,LEN(B1)+3,FIND("(",A1)-3-LEN(B1))`

Comment: I would very much appreciate VBA.
 Here is what I established that would partially work:
`If k > 0 Then
    kryterium = kryterium & ", " & """" & sNameStat & """"
  Else
     kryterium = """" & sNameStat & """"
  End If
Debug.Print kryterium
 k = k + 1
End If
 ary = Split(kryterium, """, """)`

But this only gives me one name. And I don't know how to Debug.Print what actually is inside the array...

Comment: You have used split to split the string into an array but your criteria is "Criteria1:=Array(ary),". I think that the "Array" may be confusing things, the "Array" is saying that there is an array of an array. I think just (ary) should work.

Comment: Actually after tens of tries I've found a working code:
`If k > 0 Then
                kryterium = kryterium & """" & ", |" & """" & sedziaNameStat
            Else
                kryterium = sedziaNameStat
            End If
       
            k = k + 1

ary = Split(kryterium & """" & ", |" & """", """, |""")

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$" & lastSedziaStat).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues`
Conclusion - Array(ary) works fine.
Thanks for the effort though.